# Custom Roles for authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider, sharepoint-apps

I have a provider hosted sharepoint add-in which uses a database at back end. This database has some roles like `Employer` and `Employee` in DB marked with a number. For example `1` for `Employer` and `2` for `Employee` and corresponding to every row a sharepoint email address.

In my add-in, I want to mark all my actions with `[Authorize(Role="Employer")]` attribute but I am not sure how to proceed? If I create a custom filter then, does that mean on every action, I need to call SP to get current logged in user email address -> query DB using it -> find role -> proceed or give `access denied`. It will consume lots of time as there is already a `SPContextFilter` on every action.

I was initially saving current user details in a cookie (`HttpOnly` set to true) but got to know that anyone can edit it using browser extension and impersonate users.

I am pretty new to MVC so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other way around, you will have to make a DB call for the first new request and for the subsequent requests save the user and role details in some persistent object. 
 Consider using `ViewState` objects and maybe check for null before proceeding to make a database call and populating the `ViewState` again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Varun, I will surely check this approach

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid saving user details in cookie. Check the user access with the db.
Create `User Access` Table to check whether the user has access or not
Use `Action Filter`, which will execute before the Action execute.
In controller

```
[RoleAccess]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        your code
    }
}
```

The `[RoleAccess]` is a Action filter function.
In `FilterConfig.cs`

```
public class RoleAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            var userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            if (access not accepted)
            {
                //return the user to access denied page
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { 
                {"controller","Error"},
                {"action","Error403"}
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

If the access is accepted then the user is authorized to access the requested `Action`
hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer anand. The main issue is my current user id will come from sharepoint and I will check user access from database. This checking on every action will make the application very slow, therefore, I am planning to use cache/session for maintaining some state.

Comment: This may be related to SP Add-Ins in general, but what stops people being able to access your provider hosted web front end directly, sign in with their SharePoint Online credentials - I know you would get an error "App is with indetified 'XYZ' is not installed" but is there definitely no way around that say if they create their own add in and use the same unique ID?